# Unix to Windows: Alternative to vsnprintf to determine length?

Tags: c, windows, visual-studio-2010

I am currently converting the code of one of our Linux libraries to a Windows DLL.

Within this library I have a function which takes the last parameters in a printf-way (format string,
then ellipsis). Within this function I use vsnprintf to format the supplied arguments.
Since I want to know whether I can cram the final string into a small buffer or if I'd have to allocate
memory for it, I am interested in determining the "would-be-length" of the formatted string.

To do this, I am currently using vsnprintf like this (made up example code, obviously):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void foo(const char* fmt, ...)
{
   int len = 0;
   va_list ap;

   va_start(ap, fmt);
   len = vsnprintf(0, 0, fmt, ap);
   printf("len = %d\n", len);
   va_end(ap);
}

int main(void)
{
   foo("12345%s", "67890");
   exit(0);
}
```

This usage is covered by the [Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/toc.htm):

> vsnprintf(char *restrict s, size_t n, const char *restrict format, va_list ap)
>
> *The [...] vsnprintf() [...] functions shall be equivalent to [...] snprintf().*
>
> snprintf(char *restrict s, size_t n, const char *restrict format, ...)
>
> *If the value of n is zero on a call to snprintf(), nothing shall be written, the number of bytes that would have been written had n been sufficiently large excluding the terminating null shall be returned, and s may be a null pointer.*

The problem arised as I was compiling this code on the Windows-System (Visual Studio 2010) with /analyze on. The compiler/analyzer gave me the following:

> test.c(11) : warning C6309: Argument '1' is null: this does not adhere to function specification of 'vsnprintf'
>
> test.c(11) : warning C6387: 'argument 1' might be '0': this does not adhere to the specification for the function 'vsnprintf': Lines: 7, 8, 10, 11

A quick look at the [MSDN entry for vsnprintf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/1kt27hek%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) gave me this:

> If *buffer* or *format* is **NULL**, or if count is less than or equal to zero, these functions invoke the invalid parameter handler, as described in Parameter Validation. If execution is allowed to continue, these functions return -1.

Curious enough, the above sample works nonetheless on Windows "as expected" (i.e. it returns to me the count of the characters that would be written).

But since I don't want this to rely on something unspecified I'd like to know if there is a better, official way of achieving the same, without having to hope that this won't break in some future release.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Enable C99 on your compiler, it must be available I think. Or uses http://www.ijs.si/software/snprintf/

Comment: @Geo Not on Microsoft's compilers.

Comment: This seems more a documentation problem than anything else. The debug crt sources in vs9 explicitly allow for this situation: `_VALIDATE_RETURN( (count == 0) || (string != NULL), EINVAL, -1 );` and below `if ( string==NULL) return(retval);`, so they thought about the case where count == 0 and string == NULL.

Comment: @Artefacto: Thanks for looking that up. I'll write a mail to the MSDN documentation folks. Maybe they can clarify their wording.

Comment: Consider using _vscprintf() instead.

Comment: @Hans: Thanks! That's the kind of alternative I was looking for (although I have to add ugly ifdefs now ;)). If you'd like, you can make a post so I can flag the question as answered.

Comment: Go ahead and make your own post from it and mark it answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Answer provided in comments by [Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant):

The documented [_vscprintf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vscprintf-vscprintf-l-vscwprintf-vscwprintf-l?view=vs-2019) provides this functionality on Windows,
so relying on "unspecified behaviour" is not necessary.

Comment: It's actually not "unspecified behavior", it's behavior contrary to the specification.

Comment: The MSDN `_vscprintf` doc link in this answer is out-of-date.  Here is an updated link for 2020: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/vscprintf-vscprintf-l-vscwprintf-vscwprintf-l?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 3):

Take this example from the [manual page of snprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf):

Here is how to allocate a buffer in order to fit your string.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

char *
make_message(const char *fmt, ...)
{
    int n;
    int size = 100;     /* Guess we need no more than 100 bytes. */
    char *p, *np;
    va_list ap;

   if ((p = malloc(size)) == NULL)
        return NULL;

   while (1) {

       /* Try to print in the allocated space. */

       va_start(ap, fmt);
        n = vsnprintf(p, size, fmt, ap);
        va_end(ap);

       /* If that worked, return the string. */

       if (n > -1 && n < size)
            return p;

       /* Else try again with more space. */

       if (n > -1)    /* glibc 2.1 */
            size = n+1; /* precisely what is needed */
        else           /* glibc 2.0 */
            size *= 2;  /* twice the old size */

       if ((np = realloc (p, size)) == NULL) {
            free(p);
            return NULL;
        } else {
            p = np;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know of this possibility. However I want to avoid mallocs when necessary, so this is not an exact replacement for what I was looking for. Thanks for looking that example up though :)

Comment: The best answer for this (v)snprintf on Visual studio and its difference with posix is answered here with a good sample code : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915672/snprintf-and-visual-studio-2010