# Is vsnprintf_s an appropriate replacement for deprecated vsnprintf?

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, printf

In my code (strict C, not C++), I use vsnprintf this way:

```
char* buf = NULL;
size_t sz;
sz = vsnprintf( buf, 0, format, args); // Ask vsnprintf how big a buffer we need

buf = (char*) malloc(sz + 1);
vsnprintf( buf, sz, format, args); // Now actually fill the buffer
/* Use buf in a dialog box... then: */
free(buf);
```

But MS Visual C++ (MSVS10) compiler warns:

```
warning C4996: 'vsnprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using vsnprintf_s instead.
```

However, `vsnprintf_s` does *not* have the nifty feature that when you pass NULL for the buffer it will describe how much data it *would have* printed.  Instead, it is [documented to return -1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3xd30zz%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

I feel I'm using `vsnprintf` in a safe manner by determining the necessary size, and that the recommended replacement, `vsnprintf_s` isn't the same at all.

Am I missing a better / smarter way to use `vsnprintf_s`??

Comment: You're in C++-land, stop using sprintf entirely. What you want for building strings dynamically is probably a std::stringstream

Comment: ["First of all, print the documentation about "safe/unsafe" functions from MSDN and burn it!"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2169016/mac-solution-for-safe-alternatives-to-unsafe-c-c-standard-library-function/2169107#2169107) - `vsnprintf()` is **not** deprecated, don't believe VS, it's ***crap.***

Comment: @crowder: fair enough.  My project actually is pure-C, but I happen to be using a C++ compiler at the moment.  Changing the tags, and clarifying the question.

Comment: vsnprintf can be misused very easily, it's not unreasonable to be wary of it.

Comment: According to the [documentation for VS2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek(v=vs.100).aspx), `vsnprintf` invokes the invalid parameter handler if either the buffer or format arguments are `NULL`, or if count is less than or equal to zero (See discussion in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8488671/unix-to-windows-alternative-to-vsnprintf-to-determine-length?rq=1)). I think there's a reasonable possibility that `vsnprintf_s` will have the behavior you want contrary to documentation - test it.

Comment: Unfortunately, the vsnprintf_s documentation is pretty inaccurate. It states that if the buffer is null or the count is 0, it will return -1 and set errno, but that's not exactly true. If you pass null for the buffer, 0 for the sizeOfBuffer, and 0 for the count, it will return 0 (provided you didn't pass null as the format string), and it will not set errno. Also, if you pass a real buffer and a real size but a count of 0, it will return -1 but not set errno. The documentation also states that the invalid parameter handler will be invoked if buffer is null or if count is 0. Also not true. 1/2

Comment: Neither of the workflows I described above will invoke the invalid parameter handler. The documentation states "if count <= 0". However, count is a size_t, which is typedefed as unsigned by the standard. Maybe they're looking to the future. *shrugs*. Also of note is that the MSDN documentation for vsnprintf (not _s) states that "If buffer or format is NULL, or if count is less than or equal to zero, these functions invoke the invalid parameter handler". Not true. You can pass it a null buffer and it will give you the required length (minus the null terminator) as the return value. 2/2

Comment: `vsnprintf` is not deprecated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out this question is pretty much an exact duplicate of:

[Calculating the size of an sprintf() buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9369080/calculating-the-size-of-an-sprintf-buffer)

**Summary of the answer:**

Use `_vscprintf` to figure out how big the buffer should be, then use `vsnprintf_s` to actually fill it.

Answer (score 2):

VC has finally implemented the standard `vsnprintf`. [See the ever unreliable MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1kt27hek.aspx).

Comment: It seems any criticism of the big M is sanctioned by a downvote... +1

Comment: I never said `vsnprintf` was not implemented.  It was always implemented, but also marked as deprecated, and given a `C4996` warning.

Comment: File a bug report with microsoft. `vsnprintf` is a standard function, and not deprecated by any actual authority.

Comment: It was not me, but I think that downvote may have been earned by that "See the ever unreliable MSDN." remark. I've mostly skipped the last 10 years or so, but in the preceding decade (or so), MSDN used to be "the ever reliable" documentation, actually, if memory serves. Not error-free, but one of the better ones.

Comment: @Sz. See the comments on the question, some inaccuracies are pointed out. MSDN is also full of MS nonesense written as if it's standard. The fact that they think they have a "more secure" version of it (yet until a few years ago their `vsnprintf` didn't even comply to C99) is another example. MSDN may have improved (it was garbage last I saw it), but it's still full of things that are non-standard, with little indication of what's standard and what's not (hence being unreliable).

Comment: That `vsnprintf` saga is getting kinda old, and has been beaten to death millions of times. It was a problem (an overblown one, too), but is that all that's supposed to make MSDN "ever unreliable", or are there other serious examples, too? Note: MSDN is sometimes worse than some other (even ancient) servings of the MS docs, and may be annoyingly terse here and there, or lack crossrefs, and their legacy terminology (e.g. the "Unicode" stuff) can be ridiculously confusing occasionally, but I'm not sure your arguments are convincing. I'm kinda more convinced of your bias, if anything.

Comment: @S.z, `vsnprintf` is the context of this question. I don't generally deal with WIN32, so I have little interaction with MSDN. Every time I did though, I was presented with some highly useless overview of things that never solved my problem. Once was to figure out why WIN32 Fonts that are created bold don't stay bold (on font copy? I don't remember), one was [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43899457/912144). Recently was to figure out an issue with [GetPixelFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-getpixelformat). I could never rely on MSDN, hence unreliable

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't say this is a duplicate question, as @abelenky suggests. If you want to use `vsnzprintf_s` in place of an old `vsnprintf` you need to pass `_TRUNCATE` (which expands to `((size_t)-1)`) as the `count` argument (3rd parameter).

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d3xd30zz.aspx

> If the storage required to store the data and a terminating null exceeds sizeOfBuffer, the invalid parameter handler is invoked, as described in Parameter Validation, unless count is _TRUNCATE, in which case as much of the string as will fit in buffer is written and -1 returned. If execution continues after the invalid parameter handler, these functions set buffer to an empty string, set errno to ERANGE, and return -1.

Answer (score 0):

To get the buffer size you can do this:

> size_t size = _vscprintf(format, argptr);

A good overview is available here [vsnprintf vs vsnprintf_s](http://support.tenasys.com/INtimeHelp_6/vsnprintf,%20vsnwprintf_s.html) .  Essentially vsnprintf_s returns E_INVAL error if the buffer or format paramters are null pointers.  If not null, vsnprintf_s writes up to the buffer size, truncating data that exceeds the size.