# This function or variable may be unsafe. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

Tags: c++

I'm working on a C++ DDL, however I get the following issue in some places:

```
C4996 'sprintf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using sprintf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.
```

I did try `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS`, but the issue remains.
This is the code:

```
sprintf(szDebugString, "%s: 0x%x (%s%s%i)", ptrName, (DWORD)funcPtr, interfaceName, interfaceVersion.c_str(), i);
```

Comment: Or just pass the `/wd4996` option to `cl`.

Answer (score 15):

You have to define `_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` before `#include <Windows.h>`.

Alternatively, use the safe version:

```
sprintf_s(szDebugString, sizeof(szDebugString), "%s: 0x%x (%s%s%i)",
    ptrName, (DWORD)funcPtr, interfaceName, interfaceVersion.c_str(), i);
```

Comment: Or the one present in the standard: `snprintf`.

Comment: @MartinBonner Agreed; that is better, however I am unsure if it's available in Visual Studio.

Comment: Oh gah!  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2915672/snprintf-and-visual-studio-2010.  tl;dr?  Not until VS2015.  Only 16 years after a sensible set of semantics were standardized!

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica MS were very adamant at that semantics for internal reason. They also were offering different kind of ranged for loop. All because their interbal coding style

Answer (score 5):

put this define into `stdafx.h`.

E.g.

```
#pragma once
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
```

Answer (score 5):

To turn off the warning for an entire project in the Visual Studio IDE:

1- Open the Property Pages dialog for your project.

2- Select the Configuration Properties > C/C++ > Advanced page.

3- Edit the Disable Specific Warnings property to add 4996. Choose OK to apply your changes.

Comment: you save me ( this was my first C++ project and you save me )

Comment: Thank you. The top answer doesn't work for my situation (`sprintf()` is being called by a library and it doesn't include Windows.h)

Answer (score 3):

In my point of view, on a Windows project, it is not a good idea to disable the warning; a better idea is to improve the code. Mute the warning not just keeps this potential code vulnerability unnoticed, but also blinds programmers when introducing [other potential code vulnerabilities](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb288454.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

From the docs:

> You can turn off the warning for a specific line of code by using the warning pragma, #pragma warning(suppress : 4996). You can also turn the warning off within a file by using the warning pragma, #pragma warning(disable : 4996).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-3-c4996?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(C4996)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=vs-2017